# Grep replace é, ü, ï etc

Tags: replace, grep, adobe-indesign, diacritics

For my workflow, I need to replace accented characters with a unique string (to be re-replaced in another step of the process).

But in my current Grep-rule (In InDesign's FindChangeList), this does not recognize the accented letters:

```
grep    {findWhat:"é"}  {changeTo:"!e"} //Doesn't do anything
```

To verify:

```
grep    {findWhat:"\/"} {changeTo:"\+"} //Does work: it replaces a slash with a plus sign.

grep    {findWhat:"e"}  {changeTo:"f"}  //Does work, and does not replace é to f
```

Comment: It works absolutely fine for me, both text and grep search-replace. Are you using Find/Change dialogue or scripted GREP? If it is dialogue, make sure you clear Find Format, if it is script - reset GREP/text search preferences

Comment: Does it work when you replace the `é` in your change list with its unicode value `\u00e9`? If that is the case, you saved your change list with a non-standard encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you clean the Preferences before and after the changes?

`app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = null;`